# SQL Azure distributing heavy read queries for reporting

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-roles

We are using SQL Azure for our application and need some inputs on how to handle queries that scan a lot data for reporting. Our application is both read/write intensive and so we don't want the  report queries to block the rest of the operations.

To avoid connection pooling issues caused by long running queries we put the code that queries the DB for reporting onto a worker role. This still does not avoid the database getting hit with a bunch of read only queries.

Is there something we are missing here - Could we setup a read only replica which all the reporting calls hit?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at SQL Azure Data Sync.  It will allow you to incrementally update your reporting database.

here are a couple of links to get you started

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh667301.aspx

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1821.sql-data-sync-overview.aspx

I think it is still in CTP though.

Comment: SQL Azure data sync does not seem to work from sql azure to sql azure. So is this the solution - have a Azure VM and set up SQL Server on it and have all the reporting queries hit that server?

Comment: The Data Sync Service works with SQL Azure to SQL Azure as well

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

1. Create a separate connection string for reporting, for example use a different Application Name
2. For your reporting queries use SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

This should prevent your long running queries blocking your operational queries. This will also allow your reports to get a consistent read.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Most of our reporting queries do a read committed snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about reporting I'm assuming you don't need real time data. In that case, you can consider creating a copy of your production database at a regular interval (every 12 hours for example).

In SQL Azure it's very easy to [create a copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951631.aspx):

```
-- Execute on the master database.
-- Start copying.
CREATE DATABASE Database1B AS COPY OF Database1A;
```

Your reporting would happen on Database1B without impacting the actual production database (Database1A).

Comment: Any tools out there  to do an incremental backup to database1b?

Comment: If you are going to go with a copy, why not just drop/recreate the database? Does it take too long?  Ideally, you create a copy of the production database, do your reporting off the copy and drop it when done to save the hit to you bill.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying you have a lot of read-only queries...any possibility of caching them?  (perfect since it is read-only)

What reporting tool are you using?  You can output cache the queries as well if needed.